# Error AngularJS Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: jquery, angularjs, web

This is my first post. I hope you'll help me as every time I have a question.

The error is:

> http://pastebin.com/L5jm19vu

The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);
var path = location.pathname;

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: './app/views/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController',
        })
        .when('/reparaciones', {
            templateUrl: 'app/app/views/reparaciones.html',
            controller: 'mainController',
        })
        .when('/acercade', {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/acercade.html',
            controller: 'mainController',
        })
        .when('/personalizacion', {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/personalizacion.html',
            controller: 'mainController',
        })
        .when('/tiendas', {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/tiendas.html',
            controller: 'mainController',
        })
        .when('/contacto', {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/contacto.html',
            controller: 'mainController',
        });
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: 'app/views/home.html'
        });
});
```

});

The controller:

```
    app.controller('mainController', function ($rootScope, $location){
    $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();    
     });
```

I use Angular 1.2 and the Route provider jQuery too:

```
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.30/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="./app/angular-route.js"></script>
    <scipt src="./app/innova.js"></scipt>
    <script src="./app/controlador.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Help me, please.
John.

Comment: You don't need to encapsulate your angular modules with `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: Please check if you have defined dependencies only once. This means, you write: var app = angular.module('myApp', []) only once and there after you write this without square brackets. angular.module('myApp')

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/krnitesh/8q8adny5/

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);
var path = location.pathname;
```

- Removed Angular Code from ready event and put it at the end of body
- Add link to ngRoute as it has been seprated out of core module